# Terminate ROS program

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am new in ROS.
In my program, I am launching a launch file and through which my .cpp file is executing.
In this .cpp, I check for a condition, if it doesn't satisfy I have to terminate the program.
To terminate this I have tried ros::shutdown() but it not working enough. How should I terminate this.

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250182/terminate-ros-program/) by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. I added the ***required="true"*** option to one of the  tags in my launch file.
e.g.

---

Originally posted by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) with karma: 16 on 2016-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Akhilesh,

What is going wrong when calling ros::shutdown()? Have a look at this similar question: [Properly bring down active node](http://answers.ros.org/question/221240/properly-bring-down-active-node/).

It points to the [roscpp docs on shutting down](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Shutting_Down) and another [question with a detailed answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/27655/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-stuff-before-a-node-is-shutdown/). You should be able to find all the information you need over there.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2016-12-17**:
Hi rbbg,

Thanks for responding. Actually I tried with the above step that you shared, but when I was calling ros::shutdown(), the node was being stopped but roslaunch was existing. Hence I was not able to come out of the program.

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2016-12-17**:
So I followed one step that I have mentioned in my answer and now it is working properly and shutting down too.